# Find out the moment UIView entered (scrolled into) the screen

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uikit

- UIView is a view of a MyViewController **A**
- A is initialized and its view is added as a subView of a scroll view,
  which is on **B**'s view like this:

```
View Controller B
    B View 
        Scroll View
            Image View
            Container View
                View Controller A view
```

- A's view is initialized and added as a subview in B's viewDidLoad
     method
- I have no control of B, can't use methods of UIScrollViewDelegate
- A's view is initially off screen, we can't see it

Need to somehow be notified that the A's view has been "scrolled into" the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have little control your best solution might actually be KVO. I like to avoid it though. You can create a solution with no access to anything at all. The following will take the first superview that is scroll view and try to hook to it's content offset and display when it is visible on scroll view and when it is not:

```
class MyView: UIView {

    private weak var scrollView: UIScrollView?
    private var observationContext = 0
    private(set) var isCurrentlyVisible: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if(oldValue != isCurrentlyVisible) {
                print(isCurrentlyVisible ? "Visible" : "Not visisble")
            }
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            self.findParentScrollView()
            self.attachScrollViewObserving()
        }
    }

    private func findParentScrollView() {
        var scrollView: UIView? = self.superview
        while scrollView != nil && !(scrollView is UIScrollView) {
            scrollView = scrollView?.superview
        }
        self.scrollView = scrollView as? UIScrollView
    }

    private func attachScrollViewObserving() {
        guard let scrollView = self.scrollView else { return }
        scrollView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(UIScrollView.contentOffset), options: [], context: &observationContext)
        refreshIsVisibleInScrollView()
    }

    private func refreshIsVisibleInScrollView() {
        guard let scrollView = self.scrollView else {
            isCurrentlyVisible = false
            return
        }
        let frameInScrollView = self.convert(bounds, to: scrollView)
        let visibleFrame = CGRect(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y, width: scrollView.bounds.width, height: scrollView.bounds.height)
        isCurrentlyVisible = visibleFrame.intersects(frameInScrollView) // OR visibleFrame.contains(frameInScrollView)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if &observationContext == context {
            refreshIsVisibleInScrollView()
        } else {
            super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
        }
    }

}
```

I hope you can imagine that a lot of things in here are dangerous but can be avoided if you have at least some access to your views:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
```

Here the view waits for a second to ensure that it actually is already added into view hierarchy. A better approach would be to do this in view controller like:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    myView.scrollView = self.parentScrollView
    myView.attachScrollViewObserving()
}
```

The `findParentScrollView` is also dangerous. If you can find get it directly somehow or assign it when you create the view controller `A` you would improve stability. The problem naturally is that you may have scroll view within scroll view in some cases (note that table view and collection view are scroll views as well).

The rest should be quite straight forward I hope. But note that this is not yet a bulletproof implementation. Other properties may effect visibility of your view like resizing or repositioning of your own view within its parent; changing content insets; changing size of scroll view itself; transformations... It might be an overkill trying to handle them all so just use what you believe may change.